# Stand-alone charts in GWT

Tags: gwt, charts

I've been trying to get pretty charts to work in GWT on our internal network.

Playing around with [GWT-Ext](http://gwt-ext.com)'s charts is nice, but it requires flash and is really messy to control (it seems buggy, in general).

I'd like to hear about something that works with the least amount of dependencies and it also must work without a connection to the web (so, Google' charts API isn't a solution).

**Edit:** Indeed, I would rather a library that is all client-side.

Comment: So did you get to find a good library for this?

Comment: @MikeMyers As you can see on the second answer here, I did at the time find something that was good for me. Unfortunately, it's been several years since and I no longer use that so don't know what's the "current" best

Comment: I too interested in charting API for GWT

Answer (score 9):

I'm building a GWT chart library based on Flot: http://gflot.googlecode.com 
I hope you find it useful. Contact me if you have any questions.

Comment: This seems to be very out of date, future browsers of this question.

Answer (score 7):

Googling for "GWT +sparklines" has gotten me to [gchart](http://code.google.com/p/gchart/), which seems like what I need.
From what I understand - it's all client side and requires nothing more than their JAR file.

Comment: @VladimirDyuzhev So what's the solution? is there anything more advanced?

Answer (score 2):

Google's charts actually come in two flavours, and one of them does not require interaction with Google's servers - so should satisfy your needs.

Google Image Charts is the API you are thinking of, which is an API on Google's servers that returns images.

Google Interactive Charts is a client side javascript API that renders entirely within the browser: [Google Interactive Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html)

Google provides a GWT wrapper for the interactive charts: [GWT Visualization API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)

It's not all rainbows and unicorns and you can find chart libs out there that make nicer charts, but it's pretty solid, works on all major browsers and we've been using it successfully for quite a while.

Comment: I am finding GWT Visualization API very useful but its licensing is confusing. It says it is open for commercial use. But then if I use GWT integrated version of it, say create a BarChart, it downloads the JSAPI from google's website?

That means I need to have a live connection all the time.

How will sit with the client who does not allow internal applications to access the net?

Please guide..

Comment: See their FAQ: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/faq.html

Specifically:
**Can I use visualizations offline?**
**No**; your computer must have live access to http://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use visualizations. This is because the visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method. _Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or google.visualization code to use offline_.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/ext-ux-ofcgxt/ is a nice option if you're using ext-gwt

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something that has a server side component or entirely client driven? The best ones I have seen are all flash, alas. I have done little tricks with JS and GWT before, but there is only sophisticated I will get before I go hunting for a library to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is also "sparklines" - they are available in lots of flavours (very simple charts though).

Answer (score 0):

gchart looks seriously awesome. Go with it !

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for client-side check out [flotr](http://solutoire.com/flotr/) which is based on prototype javascript library or [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) which is based on jQuery. Both work well, though flot seems like its got a bigger backing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go with flash, [XML/SWF](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/) is a wonderful tool

Answer (score 0):

+1 [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), requires jQuery though, so might not play well with GWT, I haven't used that.

Answer (score 0):

Another flash option, with a pre-built GWT integration - [Open Flash Chart / ofcgwt](http://code.google.com/p/ofcgwt/).

Comment: But is it offline or do it require a connection to their servers?

Answer (score 0):

I think that gwt-chart is a better framework for you.

Answer (score 0):

well.. i've used yahoo ui chart library (which GWT-Ext uses internally). Pretty neat solution, in the beta stage though.

Let us know the conclusion you arrive at..

Answer (score 0):

There is one open source api for charts in GWT hosted on http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rcharts/ . The API works on SVG/VML specification. You may find it quite easy to implement and use. You may find the demo at http://gwt-rcharts.appspot.com/