# Looking for an interactive pie chart to use with GWT (without extern communication)?

Tags: gwt, charts

I'm looking for a stand-alone Pie Chart which I can use in a GWT application. The Chart should be interactive, so that I can react on user input (read mouse clicks on the chart).

I've already looked at Google Chart Tools with GWT Visualization. This is exactly what I want. A simple to use PieChart class with user interaction and a simple and comprehensive data input. **Except** that the data is transfered to Google for the rendering part. The data **should not** leave the client or our server.

Comment: Are you sure the actual data is transfered to Google ?! IMO, the libraries are downloaded from Google, nothing send to Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stand-alone charts in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine found following library: [GChart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/). Rather then using Flash we'll try to draw our own. Not sure how easy this will be.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Fusion Charts? Here's the [Pie Chart showcase](http://www.fusioncharts.com/gallery/Category.asp?PieDoughnut). Its a Flash object hence you will need to use JSNI to embed the object into your widget or use a library like [GWT2SWF](http://code.google.com/p/gwt2swf/) to do it for you.

I have used Fusion Charts + GWT2SWF combination in one of my products, and would recommend it to anyone looking for a interactive flash charting tool (outside of google's toolset)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned:
"The Data should not leave the server"

With Google visualization APIs (as opposed to the chart apis) the data remains on your server, only the code is downloaded from google.

However, if you meant that you shouldnt need access to google at all, then GCharts is the only remaining and a pretty good option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out GWT-RCharts hosted on http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rcharts/ . It is stand alone i.e doesn't have external dependency like Visualization. The API works on SVG/VML specification so no plugin dependency. You may find it quite easy to install, implement and use. You can find the demo at http://gwt-rcharts.appspot.com/