# Does GWT have built-in support for charting?

Tags: gwt

Does GWT have built-in support for charting?
-Ajay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not have charts built in.

This question gives many options: [Stand alone charts in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

The [GWT Visualization API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) used with [Google Interactive Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this GWT Chart Library.
[Clientsidegchart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/?redir=1)
[Live Demo](http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/live-demo/v2_7/com.googlecode.gchart.gchartdemoapp.GChartDemoApp/GChartDemoApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it has charts built-in , but there are many charts for GWT

this question has a few

[Stand-alone charts in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

Answer (score 0):

The core UI library does not include charting. I use [Google Chart Tools (aka Visualization) 1.1 Library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) for charting in GWT.