# Using charts with gwt

Tags: gwt, charts

I am doing some stuff with gwt, Now i need to draw charts. Actually pie chart and line chart.

Is there any library for chart which works well with gwt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stand-alone charts in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Google API Libraries for Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/#Google_API_Libraries_for_Google_Web_Toolkit). There you will find a link to [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)

Comment: Note that this is dependent on Googles servers. If you don't have internet access the chart generation will fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is also  [OFCGWT](http://code.google.com/p/ofcgwt/)  chart widget for GWT based on Open Flash Chart 2. Here is its [demo](http://ofcgwt.googlecode.com/svn/demo/Demo.html)
Except this you can check out these:

1. [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)
2. [clientsidegchart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/)
3. [RaphaelJS](https://code.google.com/p/raphael4gwt/) GWT wrapper, there is also one called raphaelGWT which is not developed actively.

Answer (score 1):

I've already use Google Charts, and I preffer 
[GWT-HighCharts](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/) you can see why checking it showcase.

Comment: But keep in mind, that HighCharts is not free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rcharts/ and its demo at http://gwt-rcharts.appspot.com/ with code snippets on how to use it, which is quite easy.