# GWT widget library and MVP pattern

Tags: gwt

Can someone recommend a good widget library that is compatible/easy to use with GWT's MVP pattern? I'm especially interested in a library with good chart support. Thx

Answer (score -2):

I used http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvp/ for add MVP. Not the easiest solutions but have all what you need, and added chart support manually.

Looks on [Stand-alone charts in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

Comment: The original poster requested a widget library compatible with GWT's MVP support.  This answer proposes a library that provides alternate MVP support. It does not answer the question.

I recommend it is 'un-answered' so that a valid answer may be submitted.

Comment: @ianmayo can you provide better answer?

Comment: afraid not - my interest is because I'm currently struggling with the same question.

I'm warming to the SmartGWT widget library, but its guidance explicitly states to avoid using GWTs MVP implementation.

I suspect I'll end up not using a widget library, as per the considered view at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867451/best-gwt-widget-library

Comment: See this component library http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/ this is a implementation in gwt of Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: @ianmayo I successfully made a proof-of-concept mixing GWTP and Sencha's GXT 3. The latter being respectful of modern GWT practices, it works well with MVP.

Comment: @PhiLho do you intend publishing it?  I guess you could dump it into a GitHub repository and provide a link from this page for anybody investigating the subject.  You wouldn't necessarily have to support the sources.

Comment: @ianmayo Perhaps someday... There isn't much to it, it is a classical application, just using Sencha's components instead of pure GWT ones. Meanwhile, if you search the gwt-cx project (on Google Code, IIRC), it is a more sophisticated demo of GWTP in pure GWT, GXT 3 and even SmartClient, I think.