# Chart and plotting API for GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to find a chart and plotting api that can be used in GWT using java, not javascript.  The only problem I am having is the ones I have found require an internet connection which where this code will go cannot have an internet connection.  Does any one know of such an API?  Here are that ones that I found, but again can't use.
 https://code.google.com/p/charts4j I know this one requires a connection.
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted

Not 100% sure on this one.  If anyone has used it and can let me know if it requires a connection let me know. Also if anyone know how to get java swing to work in GWT that would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stand-alone charts in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251/stand-alone-charts-in-gwt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Client-side GChart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/). All in your app - no loading visualizations from external servers.

Comment: thanks for that @Boris Should it be any concern that there hasn't been an update for two years, and it's been a year since the admin has replied to any issues?

Comment: @ianmayo It's a consideration, for sure. I am currently using it in a commercial project quite confidently, having found no other charting frameworks and having tested GChart thoroughly in my application. It's open source so you can hack at it if there's a bug (I haven't found one yet after more than a year of use).

Comment: Having said the above, it's still worthwhile to search every once in a while for a more up-to-date and actively maintained client-side charting framework, especially if GChart's support continues to dwindle. Post it here if you find one.

Comment: @Boris: There are a few others... Some come with a GWT API, and others only with a JavaScript API, but for many use cases, it's straightforward to wrap the calls (or objects) for GWT.

Comment: Thanks for this @BorisBrudnoy. Do you know by any chance if this API supports the selections of the charts or just places the image onto the screen.

Comment: @KennyWatts GChart charts are not simply rendered images. If by "selections" you mean mouse event handling then yes, it can do that (see the [GChart Live Demo](http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/live-demo/v2_7/com.googlecode.gchart.gchartdemoapp.GChartDemoApp/GChartDemoApp.html), especially the Pie Chart, for possibilities).

Answer (score 5):

I just finished a little presentation on that topic. In there, I'm taking a short and somewhat subjective look at:

- [clientsidegchart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/)
- [gflot](http://code.google.com/p/gflot/)
- [dojox.charting](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/charting.html)
- [Ico](http://reverserisk.com/ico/) (and other Raphael based libs)
- [GXT charts](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/)
- [Smart GWT HTML5 Charts](http://www.smartclient.com/product/#html5Charts)
- [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/)
- [amCharts JavaScript Charts](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/)
- [Google Chart Tools API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)
- [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (and other server side libs)

Only the last two of them require an active internet connection.

Here's the link to a PDF snapshot of the presentation: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0oR9hvG2VjoRDZZR20zYjVLalU

Answer (score 0):

This is another open source api for charts in GWT hosted on http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rcharts/ you may find it useful. The API works on SVG/VML specification. You may find it quite easy to implement and use. You may find the demo at http://gwt-rcharts.appspot.com/